# Tableview lags, and glitches while scrolling due to images loading in each cell

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, image

Hey Guys! Me again! Can someone provide me with some example code of how to properly load images in a tablecell without making the tableview glitch while scrolling. For example if you look at fandago's app, when scrolling through their movies you can see that the image is loaded asynchronously so that the scroll isnt jumping, lagging, or glitchy. Thanks in advance. Right now I have the images loading just fine but it is glitchy as i scroll because the images are loading on main thread. I am creating an app very similar to fandango.

PS I am downloading these images via xml. (you know what i mean)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has an example of what you're looking for here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html

Comment: Excellent example! Now I just gotta dig in and see what there doin, and how their doin it! Wish me luck! Thanks!!